# Golang: sql syntax error at Query method of sql package

Tags: go

Here is my code

```
rows, err := r.db.Query(`SELECT * FROM ?`, couriersTable)
```

and I got the following error:

```
pq: syntax error at or near "?"
```

I tried to use '%s' instead of '?', and got no difference.

Comment: Parameter placeholders like `?` (or `$N` in other SQL dialects), are for __values__ ONLY. A table name, or column name, func name, etc... those are NOT values, those are __identifiers__.

Comment: really? So i can't use variables for tables? It's crazy. How should i change a table name? So inconvenient

Comment: Oh yeah, i know. SPrintf

Comment: You can use variables, you just can't use the SQL parameter placeholders to send identifiers to the db backend, at least not with plain queries. For example, for identifiers you can use plain interpolation (with `fmt`) or string concatenation (with `+`). You should however filter the variables' values through a whitelist, otherwise your code will be subject to SQL injection attacks. Another alternative is to use SQL functions that execute dynamic SQL, then you could pass the identifiers as plain text  arguments for the placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following snippet will produce the expected result:

```
rows, err := r.db.Query(fmt.Sprintf(`SELECT * FROM %s`, couriersTable))
```

You can read [Using prepared statements](https://go.dev/doc/database/prepared-statements) to receive more insight.